# DC power through a female socket

Tags: dc

I have a solar panel and I would like to use an extension cord. I know this works (heavy duty extension cord) but the guy cut the ends off of the cord to just use the wire (see video links below). I don't want to do that. I would like to add a female socket to the wire ends and plug in the extension cord. I have a few questions about this (I asked at Home Depot and Lowe's and no one had a clue).

My questions:

1. Will it work?
2. Will a female plug, say from Lowe's or HD, work with DC power? Everything involved can easily handle the amps.
3. Could I possibly use a household socket?
4. Do they make DC female sockets or household sockets?

**Edit:**

Here's the [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HYT_wuwcz80) that gave me the idea for the extension cord.

And [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zdeg5ACyP_4) gave me the idea for the plug. They use a male plug. **Does that matter?**

Comment: You mentioned that some guy cut the ends off of the cord. What are you referring to? Is there a link we can look at? Or is that a friend of yours that did it?

Comment: It was a video on youtube. I just dont want to ruin the extension cord. This will in no way be used for ac power. The other end of the cord will go to the charge controller, either bare wire if i have to cut the end off or ill buy a male socket and some wire and do it that way.

Comment: Could you please edit your question and post a link to the video? That way we know exactly what you're talking about. Thanks!

Comment: Edit is posted :)

Answer (score 3):

**Never try using a regular AC extension cords with plugs intended for primary line power for anything other than their intended use.** Likewise do not ever try using AC mains fixture outlets and plugs for non-mains applications. There is strong reasoning here that rests in the interests of safety to you and others nearby. It also helps protect equipment from getting the wrong voltages applied to them.

Think about the huge safety problem and potential damage that could occur if you start cobbling up your low voltage DC solar panel with AC electrical plugs and then someone decides to take the other end of your cords and plug it into live AC mains.

There are a plethora of various types of connectors made that would be suitable for your DC extensions. Take a look at a web site such as Mouser.com or DigiKey.com and be overwhelmed you how many connector choices there are for DC applications.

Comment: It should be mentioned that there's no technical reason why it wouldn't work. It **should still never be done**.

Comment: OK i went to digikey and there is a lot of stuff but i have no idea what i need.

Comment: A friend once shipped some equipment to Elbonia, it needed a DC power setup so they reasoned that using easily available UK mains plugs & sockets would be OK as no-one in Elbonia has ever seen one. That was fine until the kit nearly set fire to the Elbonian Embassy in the UK where it had ended up... so yeah, NEVER do it no matter how idiot-proof you think it is - there is always a better idiot somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a non-AC power connector. For this purpose, Jones connectors are the obvious choice. Try http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/connectors-interconnects/blade-type-power-connectors/1442716 and select Jones plugs and Jones sockets. These will carry 15 amps / pin. They're not wicked expensive, either.

Answer (score -1):

Just the cable is fine. But be sure never to connect the other end to the wall (120 Vac).
you can use the L for your positice load and the N for your ground.

Here is a reference for the color normaly use :
https://elise.ema.gov.sg/safety/images/cable1.jpg

Comment: AC socket is the same as DC. Calbea are made for 15 Amps you will have no issues.

Comment: The solar panel has just positive and negative and the extension cord has the two plug wires and a ground. I have researched how to wire it but what do you think?